# How to format thousands from digit a with a point

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'am looking for the best way to format thousands from digit a with a point. I am creating a view from an other table and I need for some columns to have this type of format.

ex : 10000 -> 10.000

Thank you in advance for your possible answers !

Comment: Personally, I would write a UDF

Comment: What is UDF ? ( sorry i am new on Hadoop world)

Comment: UDF is custom function, you can use in hive. You can look at the following blog: https://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/08/10/guide-to-writing-hive-udfs.html

Comment: oh ok, thanks again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is way how to do it without UDF but it can be performance issue. But for small sets of data it works:
You can use the following combination of build-in functions:

```
// Template
select reverse(concat_ws(".",split(reverse(<column-to-format>),"(?<=\\G.{3})")));
// sample 1 - format number 12345678
select reverse(concat_ws(".",split(reverse("12345678"),"(?<=\\G.{3})")));
// sample 2 - format number 10000
select reverse(concat_ws(".",split(reverse("10000"),"(?<=\\G.{3})")));
```

Explanation for sample 1 with number 12345678

```
1. reverse("12345678") Result: 87654321
2. split(reverse("12345678"),"(?<=\\G.{3})")")) Result: array [876,543,21]
3. concat_ws(".",split(reverse("10000"),"(?<=\\G.{3})")) Result "876.543.21"
4. finally reverse it back. Result: "12.543.876"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you detail a bit what does that do ?

Comment: Ok - go from inside of functions. 1. reverse(<column-to-format>) - we need to reverse the input because of following regex. 2. split(reverse(<column-to-format>),"(?<=\\G.{3})") / split the string into elements which length is 3. 3. concat array which is create by split function and add the dot between the strings. 4. it is still in reverse order therefore reverse it back. We have to use reverse function because the regex process string from left to right and without this the result could be for example like this 100.00 what is incorrect.